# Facebook authentication issues

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

I'm using the code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0 to set up a facebook authentication form, but it gives me an error in the JavaScript console "ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" "file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js".

I changed the line js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"; to js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"; and that seems to fix the problem, but then it comes up with a new error: "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

Does anyone have a chunk of JavaScript code that works for Facebook login and logout procedures?

Comment: That code is correct. You just need to configure your app on https://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: It was working for me and few minuts ago I suddenly get this error 
GET  http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED